# Find the Error of a linearization by integration

Tags: calculus

Let's say $E(x)$ is the error between a function $f(x)$ and its first order linearization $L(x)$, so:

$$E(x)=f(x)-L(x)=f(x)-f(a)-f'(a)(x-a)$$

Then by the Mean-Value Theorem for $u\in(a,x)$:

$$\frac{E'(x)}{x-a}=\frac{f'(x)-f'(a)}{x-a}=f''(u)$$
$$E'(x)=f''(u)(x-a)$$

**Question:**
How can I show by integration from here that: $$E(x)=\frac{f''(s)}{2}(x-a)^2$$

**My attempt:**

Integrating $E'(x)=f''(u)(x-a)$ I get $E(x)=\frac{f''(u)}{2}(x-a)^2+C$

How do I get from $E(x)=\frac{f''(u)}{2}(x-a)^2+C$ to $E(x)=\frac{f''(s)}{2}(x-a)^2$?

Comment: $u$ depends on $x$! So integrating the right hand side is a pretty bad idea. If you do, you need some mean value type theorem.

Comment: @user251257 I already used the Mean Value Theorem, so I think $f''(u)$ is constant and not depending on $x$

Comment: why should $f''$ being constant, that is $f$ being a quadratic polynomial? You need a mean value type argument, why there is some $s$ such that $f''(s)(x-a)^2 = 2\int_a^x f'(u_t)(t-a) dt$ where $u_t$ depends on the integration variable $t$.

Comment: @user251257 $u$ is a constant, somewhere between $a$ and $x$. Therefore $f''(u)$ is also constant.

Comment: the mean value theorem says ... for $a,x$ there exists some $u$ between $a$ and $x$ such that $E'(x) = f''(u)(x-a)$. So $u$ depends on $f'$, $a$, and $x$. In fact, $u$ is continuous in $x$ only under additional conditions. So when you integrate $E'(x) = f''(u)(x-a)$, you vary $x$ and thus also $u$. So you can't pull $f''(u)$ out of the integral without explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $E(a) = 0$ to get $C = 0$. I assume that $s$ is just some number between $x$ and $a$, i.e., $u = s$.